# Using quit/q in a function causes RStudio to fatal error

Tags: r, rstudio

More of a curiosity but when you use `q` or `quit` inside of a function inside of R studio it causes a fatal error as seen here:

[image]

But the same function in rgui causes R to stop as usual.  And using just `q()` in RStudio closes R as expected.  Why does `q` in a function cause RStudio to literally bomb?  Is this a local issue?  Can others replicate it?

Example function that causes the bomb:

```
FUN <- function() q()
FUN()
```

Here's my `sessionInfo`:

```
R Under development (unstable) (2013-09-04 r63830)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.1.0

RStudio Version 0.97.551
```

Comment: In case someone is tempted to inform the developers, it looks like it's already been done: http://support.rstudio.org/help/discussions/problems/8522-wrapping-the-quit-function

Comment: Good call it looks like it is indeed reproducible on multiple OSes as well.

Comment: Using SO to report obvious bugs should be deprecated.

Comment: Wasn't obvious until it was confirmed.  Generally, I assume it's me not the code that is in error.

Comment: I cannot replicate this on Windows 7 using RStudio v0.97.551. It works as expected.

Comment: This still appears to be a problem as of RStudio v0.99.463