# Why does R produce an error when calling quit() inside a function and can this be avoided?

Tags: r, function, quit

So I was messing around with some R code and found something that seemed interesting to me. Specifically when I call quit() function it executes without a problem, however when I place the quit function within another function R says the following.

```
poshQuit<- function(){
                      quit()
                             }


poshQuit()

R session aborted. R encountered a fatal error. The session was terminated.
```

Now this isnt the end of the world as I was just idly messing about in code but I am interested as to why this might be the case and if there are any ways this error can be avoided.

Thanks

Comment: I can reproduce this with RStudio but not from a terminal. I suspect this is related to the evaluation magic that enables RStudio's debugging facilities. You should report the issue on the RStudio forums.

Comment: It has been reported several times.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, interesting that it only seems to occur in RStudio. @TylerRinker, was there any conclusion to those reports?

Comment: musto, you can hop over to the RStudio forums and bugzilla pages and find out for yourself, y'know.

Comment: I asked the same question a while back; see the comments http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18797541/using-quit-q-in-a-function-causes-rstudio-to-fatal-error

Comment: Thanks for your replies. @TylerRinker your link goes to a discussion which links to an Rstudio forum which apparently doesnt exist anymore. Carl the only thing I could find on the Rstudio forum was the following, which seems to provide no concrete answers

https://support.rstudio.com/hc/communities/public/questions/200657137-wrapping-the-quit-function?locale=en-us